# error: cannot convert 'double (evaluator::*)(double, double)' to 'double (*)(double, double)' in assignment

Tags: c++, function, pointers, scope

I got that error , when I work with classes I got this error using pointers to function. My function 'ope' function how can I solve

```
    evaluator::function(){
    double (*ope) (double,double) ;
    ope=&evaluator::add;
}

double evaluator::add( double a, double b){
    return (a+b);
    }
```

Comment: A pointer to a function is not the same as a pointer to a member function.

Comment: Did my answer solve your problem? If so, you should accept it by clicking the checkmark next to it. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 1):

This:

```
double (*ope)(double, double);
```

should be:

```
double (evaluator::*ope)(double, double);
//      ^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

because you are using a pointer to member.

Answer (score 0):

use the follow declaration:

```
double (A::*func)(double, double)
```

and make the calling like this:

```
return ((*this).*func)(5, 4);
```

hope it helped.

```
class A {
public:
    double foo();
    double foo2(double, double);
};

double A::foo() {
    double (A::*func)(double, double);
    func = &A::foo2;
    return ((*this).*func)(5, 4);
}

double A::foo2(double a, double b) {
    return a + b;
}
```